# script to Rename files in a Directory

Tags: unix

I am creating a script to rename 3 files in a directotry, if the files exist

for Ex. I have the files as

```
customer.txt
account.txt
reference.txt
```

Need to rename them as

```
customer_arrivaldate.txt
account_arrivaldate.txt
reference_arrivaldate.txt
```

I am taking the file names in a text file and then renaming them

Iam doing something like

```
for var1 in `cat ${directory}file1.txt`
do
   file_name=${var1}_arrivaldate.txt
```

I need to modify them directly, kindly suggest some modifications

Comment: Are you sure about the reference_arrival.txt? Do you mean reference_arrivaldate.txt here as well? My answer appends strips .txt and appends _arrivaldate.txt to all .txt files in the current directory.

Comment: Ok cool, then I'm pretty sure my solution works fine for you.

Comment: I should not move, I need to create 3 such files suffixes with that day's date.There will be other files with different arrival Times.

Comment: Ok I did not understand that from your problem description. Updated slightly, is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
dateVar="2014-11-16"
for file in *.txt ; do mv $file ${file//.txt/_$dateVar.txt} ; done
```

Explanation: All files in current directory ending with .txt will be renamed to $filename -txt +dateVar+.txt

Comment: @ mattias, the files will arrive daily in the same dir, I need to rename that particular days files only.If i use *.txt, it renames all files in that dir, which is not requirement.

Comment: @Naaz: Well this information is kind of not in your original problem statement :) Do you need to listen for new files then? Or manually run the script? If listen, then I would recommend something like http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html. If manual run of your script is ok, I guess you need to filter out the files you change the names of, based on some $TODAYSDATE-ish kind of thing.